# VSS 6 get latest version window does not show

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

Unfortunately we are using VSS6 in our company!

When i am rty to get latest version, this popup window does not show, I need this window to checking recursive option.
I have this problem since today. 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have inadvertently ticked the option to not show the dialog box. Try holding down the **Shift** key while clicking Get Latest Version. This should force the dialog to appear.

You can then uncheck the 'Only show this dialog when Shift key is down' checkbox to ensure you don't have to hold down Shift every time.